# Manhwa about a mage who dies while fighting a dragon and then reincarnates as a boy on Earth

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

It's about a mage who was incredibly powerful but died while fighting a dragon, the mage then reincarnates as a boy on Earth. The guy also had white hair before he died as a result of being so strong. that’s about all I can remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When you say the mage reincarnated on Earth, do you mean _present day_ Earth...?

Comment: All of these tropes are pretty common. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one candidate and it’s not a bad manwha even if it’s not the one you’re looking for. It’s even completed.

***[I Am the Sorcerer King](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/krlvrzv/i-am-the-sorcerer-king)***.

He died in a previous life fighting a dragon. He used to have long white hair and the dragon was happy that someone had reached his level before killing the MC.
Then he is reborn in a world (Earth) that is being attacked by monsters coming out of rifts and he uses his knowledge/power to make his mom healthy and protect Earth.